# iOS6 and below: will UDID change if user switches mac

Tags: ios, iphone, uuid, mac-address, udid

for iOS6 and below :

I read that UDID is calculated as 
UDID = SHA1(serial + ECID + wifiMac + bluetoothMac)
Lets say , User switches from WIFI to cellular,wifi to ethernet(maybe) ,the mac address would change here.

Will UDID change in this case or is it fixed to use wifi mac only ? 
My problem is, my identifier should not change even if user switches network type . so , obviously i cannot use mac . 
Could anyone help me on this ?

for iOS7 onwards , we have to use identifierForVendor which mostly uses bundle identifier , so its not a problem.

Comment: Not the UDID will not change. But support < iOS 7 is currently impossible do to Apples requirements.

Comment: u mean , UDID will not change in my case , but what if user's wifi network interface is down(crashed/not working ) and is currently using cellular network . Wont it get changed in this case ?

Comment: Apple did not release any documentation about how the UDID is create. Thus there is no prove it will use the mac address. But why are you still looking to using UDID since you can use it anymore.

Comment: for people  using <iOS 7

Comment: But you can not target iOS 6 any more. Minimal is iOS 7, thus why?

Comment: ohh is it , i did not know this .which means i can happily use identifierForVendor for all ?

Comment: minimum is iOS7 for App Store, but there could be iOS6 devices on the field for which user has refused to update. I cannot force them to update , just that my app should work .

Comment: If you set your deployment target to iOS 7, then your app can not be installed on iOS 6 devices.

Comment: Correct , but we cannot do that. iOS 5 is minimum for us. Cant help

Comment: But, Thanks for the information on UDID part. I will test it out.

Comment: You can not submit apps to the app store that support anything lower then iOS 7. Since you need to use Xcode 7 or newer to build apps for the appstore. Xcode 7 does not support ARMv6 which is needed to to support iOS 6. Thus your problem does not exists since your can not support iOS 5 or 6.

Comment: Why would the MAC address change? It shouldn't, not by itself. It doesn't matter if you are connected to a WiFi network or not, the WIFi adapter MAC address shouldn't change, unless a user did so, which is not possible on non-jailbroken devices AFAIK.

Comment: @Losiowaty he ment if the WiFi module is broken thus the system can't access the mac address. Still this is a none issue because you can not support iOS 5 or 6.